# Rotate text using Graphics environment over LogLogPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, textalignment

Consider the following code:

```
myPlot = LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True];

rotatedText = 
  Graphics[{Rotate[Text["Rotated Text", {0.3, 0.9}], 
     45 Degree]}];

Show[myPlot, rotatedText]
```

It is assumed to show a rotated text over `LogLogPlot`. However, probably, `LogLogPlot` distorts the rotation transformation, and it looks bad:

[image]

In old versions of Mathematica, I used this command:

```
rotatedText = 
  Graphics[{Text[Style["Rotated text", 18, Black], Scaled[{0.2, 0.4}],
      Left, {3, -2.7}]}];
```

It works well with the plot, however, when I save the plot in .pdf format, it does this wrongly for some complicated plots - it simply does not show the rotated text (plots below - how it looks in Mathematica and what I get after saving in .pdf):

[image]
[image]

I use Mathematica 13.2 on Windows 11. How to fix the problem?

Comment: Why not: `myPlot = LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True
  , Epilog -> {Text[Rotate["Rotated Text", 30 Degree], {0.3, 0.9}]}
  ]` ? Can it fit with your existing code?

Comment: @Syed : For some reason, the text does not show up in my existing code example where there is the issue with .pdf.

Comment: @Syed : maybe I should adjust the coordinates using `Log[x_appear], Log[y_appear]`.

Comment: If it is a pdf conversion issue, then please include `$Version` and information about the converter. You will have to do some image transformation otherwise the canvas is that of a LogLogPlot whereas `Graphics` canvas is linear. I think it is not the positioning but the rotation that is giving it a spread out look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) with [`Scaled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) coordinates

```
rotatedText = 
  Graphics[{Rotate[Text["Rotated Text", {0.3, 0.9}], 31  Degree]}];

myPlot = LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True,
  Epilog -> Inset[rotatedText, Scaled[{0.1, 0.18}]]]
```

[image]